# gcc auto-vectorization fails in a reduction loop

Tags: c++, gcc, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to compile my code with auto-vectorization flags but I encounter a failure in a very simple reduction loop:

```
double node3::GetSum(void){
    double sum=0.;
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) sum+=c_value[i];
    return sum;
}
```

where the `c_value[i]` array is defined as

```
class node3{
private:
    double c_value[9];
```

The auto-vectorization compilation returns:
    Analyzing loop at node3.cpp:10

```
node3.cpp:10: note: step unknown.
node3.cpp:10: note: reduction: unsafe fp math optimization: sum_6 = _5 + sum_11;

node3.cpp:10: note: Unknown def-use cycle pattern.
node3.cpp:10: note: Unsupported pattern.
node3.cpp:10: note: not vectorized: unsupported use in stmt.
node3.cpp:10: note: unexpected pattern.
node3.cpp:8: note: vectorized 0 loops in function.

node3.cpp:10: note: Failed to SLP the basic block.
node3.cpp:10: note: not vectorized: failed to find SLP opportunities in basic block.
```

I really do not understand why it can't determine the basic block for SLP for example.
Moreover I guess I did not understand what really is the "unsupported use in stmt": the loop here simply sums a sequential access array.

Could such problems be caused by the fact that `c_value[]` is defined in the `private` of the class?

Thanks in advance.

Note: compiled as `g++ -c -O3 -ftree-vectorizer-verbose=2 -march=native node3.cpp` and also tried with more specific `-march=corei7` but same results. GCC Version: 4.8.1

Comment: I don´t much have experience with vectorization, but I strongly believe that there is a issue with `sum+=c_value[i]`. If you change your code by somenthing like `tmp[0] = c_value[0];
 for(int i=1;i<8;i++) tmp[i] = tmp[i-1] + c_value[i];` (just a code with no self dependency), I believe you will get a vectorized code. Try somehow to avoid self-referencing variables.

Comment: @wesley.mesquita I tried your suggestion but I still don't get that loop vectorized. The compilation returns `note: not vectorized: no vectype for stmt: tmp ={v} {CLOBBER}; scalar_type: double[8]`. My understanding is that in the loop the variable `tmp[i]` is assigned using `tmp[i-1]`, which belongs to a previous iteration. This, i think, leads to the "unsupported use in stmt".

Comment: Have you tried `ffast-math`? Without it, the compiler is not allowed to reorder floating-point operations.

Comment: Yes with fast math I get a very slick one movapd and three addpd, then a haddpd instruction.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to vectorize the loop at the end with the following trick:

```
double node3::GetSum(void){
    double sum=0.,tmp[8];
    tmp[0]=c_value[0]; tmp[1]=c_value[1]; tmp[2]=c_value[2]; tmp[3]=c_value[3];
    tmp[4]=c_value[4]; tmp[5]=c_value[5]; tmp[6]=c_value[6];tmp[7]=c_value[7];
    for(int i=0;i<8;i++) sum+=tmp[i];
    return sum;
}
```

where I created the dummy array `tmp[]`. This trick, together with another compilation flag i.e., `-funsafe-math-optimizations` (@Mysticial: this is actually the only thing I need, `-ffast-math` with other things I apparently don't need), makes the auto-vectorization successful.

Now, I don't really know if this solution really speeds-up the execution. It does vectorize, but I added an assign operation so I'm not sure if this should run faster. My feeling is that on the long run (calling the function many times) it does speed-up a little, but I can't prove that.
Anyway this is a possible solution to the vectorization problem, so I posted as an answer.

Comment: is it possible that `node3.c_value` is misaligned?  i think gcc requires some alignment, which it can force for a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's annoying that the freedom to vectorize reductions is coupled with other (literally) unsafe optimizations.  In my examples, a bug is surfacing (with gcc but not g++) with the combination of -mavx and -funsafe-math-optimizations, where a pointer which should never be touched gets clobbered.
Auto-vectorization doesn't consistently speed up such short loops, particularly because the sum reduction epilogue with the hadd instruction is slow on the more common CPUs.